# How do I prevent Git changing text files between commit and pull/clone?

Tags: git

We have abig problem in that one programmer commits a menustring text file to Git, the others pull it and it no longer works. Git shows the file as changed but the diff finds no differences. I can see that it changed the CR LF at the end of each line. How do we tell it not to do this as it causes havoc in our package build process.
Some use it from Linux, others from the Windows command and some from Totoise Git(myself)

Comment: `git config --global core.autocrlf true`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+config+eol+conversion

Answer (score 1):

Git is a mess in terms of changing the EOL formats.... i would rather tell it to not mess with it, unless you *really* mean to. Add this to `.git/info/attributes`

```
*   -text
```

That should be enough to avoid git from changing any EOL stuff.